# Ionic2 : Add platform doesn't work

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, platform

Command:

> ionic cordova:platform add android

Output:

```
| Executing cordova command: cordova platform add android --save 
[ERROR] An error occurred while running the above command (exit code 1):
Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
```

**ionic --version**

**3.0.0-beta.4**

**cordova --version**

**6.5.0**

**npm --version**

**4.1.2**

**node --version**

**v7.7.4**

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

You don't need to use `beta` tags here.please use as shown below.[**Doc is here.**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/intro/installation/)

```
 >  npm install -g ionic cordova
```

Create a new folder as `Ionic2` and then move to that folder..

```
> d:\ionic2>  ionic start myfirstapp blank --v2

> d:\ionic2\myfirstapp >  ionic serve
```

**OLD Answer**

You have to do like this.

*remove it first*

```
> ionic platform rm android
```

*then add it again*

```
>ionic platform add android
```

Comment: '>ionic platform rm android'
    'The platform command is no longer available. To find out more about the equivalent please run: ionic cordova:platform --help'


    '>ionic cordova:platform rm android'
    'Executing cordova command: cordova platform remove android - -   save [ERROR] An error occurred while running the above command (exit code 1):'
'    Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.'                                         **This comment is so messed up but please bare it.**     @Sampath

Comment: you have mentioned `Ionic 3.0.0-beta.4`.can you share the url of that git repo?

Comment: Actually I don't have it. I have used command  'npm install -g ionic'  @Sampath

Comment: npm install -g ionic@beta

Comment: >npm install -g ionic update                                                                           ** Even this command gave me error now.   **                                              npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm ERR! node v7.7.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
 I have Git installed and path is also given for /Git

Comment: No, please see the **Update** section of the above answer and follow that procedure.

Comment: Ionic serve. this command is working properly , but i am unable to add any plugins and any platforms too.

Comment: ionic start project_name --blank --v2

Comment: can you run project locally?

Comment: I uploaded that question only. ionic cordova:platform add android.

Comment: where you have seen such CLI command? can you share the link?